# VueJS 2 show some HTML if a Function prop was passed

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

## Question

In VueJS 2 how do you show some HTML if a Function prop was passed to the component.

## Example

```
<template>
  <div v-if="backBtn" @click="$emit('backBtn')">Back Button</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      backBtn: Function
    }
  }
</script>
```

I can do this by passing a separate prop to key the v-if off of but I'm trying to do this will the one prop.

I created a Fiddle for this issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Michael_Warner/rz6hyd7b/4/)

Comment: To pass a prop, you need `:backBtn="btnClicked"` instead of `@backBtn="btnClicked"` (i.e. `:` as opposed to `@`). In your case you would also need the `@backBtn` since you are also emitting an event with that name (not sure why though)

Comment: You are correct I will fix that but the issue remains.

Comment: If you look at the console, there is a warning: `[Warning] [Vue warn]: Attribute ":backbtn" is ignored on component <my-btn> because the component is a fragment instance: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment_Instance`

Comment: So you need `:back-btn="btnClicked"`

Comment: I refactored the Fiddle so you can always see the click event working. So we can rule that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work,

you can add more definition with `!== undefined`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="backBtn !== undefined" @click="$emit('backBtn')">Back Button</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      backBtn: {
        type: Function,
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

but as mentioned, that should work already, so you error may be somewhere else.

---

after seeing your code, I see what the issue is. it's a case issue

use `:back-btn` instead of `:backBtn`

this happens only if you're using vue runtime only (without the compilation)

read more here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

---

you can solve it also by passing the function only

https://jsfiddle.net/rz6hyd7b/7/

```
Vue.component('my-btn', {
  props: {
    backbtn: {
      type: Function
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <div v-if="backbtn" @click="backbtn">Back Button</div>
    </div>
   `
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: 'my-btn',
  methods: {
        btnClicked: function(){
      console.log('adsf')
    }  
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      Show Btn => <my-btn :backbtn="btnClicked"></my-btn>
      </br>
      Hidden Btn => <my-btn></my-btn>
  </div>
  `
});
```

Comment: I agree it looks like that should work but for some reason it does not. I created a fiddle to verify if having more definition and removing the environment has any effect and it does not.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction sir and as @AbM said using the v-bind (:) can pass the function through. working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Michael_Warner/rz6hyd7b/6/

Comment: though it depends on your use, you can do it without defining `bind` AND `prop`, by passing function as prop only. Based on the question, I thought that's what you're trying to achieve.